# Number of integer $k$-tuples with sum $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, set-partition

I wish to know how many elements are there in the set
$$
S_{n,k} = \left\{(n_1,\ldots, n_k): \forall i,n_i \in \mathbb Z, n_i \geq 0, \sum_i n_i = n\right\}.
$$

It appears to me that we have a simple formula for $|S_{n,k}|$ presumably in terms of binomial coefficients, but I find it hard to come up with that.

At least for $k=3,$ we have the simple expression $|S_{n,k}| = \frac12 (n+1)(n+2)$, and this is very easy to derive. But after this point, the sums gets very complicated.

Comment: "Stars and bars" is a common approach

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that!

Answer (score 0):

We wish to put $k-1$ bars among $n$ stars. The number of ways to do this is simply
$$
{n+k-1 \choose k-1}.
$$